# How to use getInitial?

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to figure out how the getInitial function works. I generated my simulated data:

```
n<-100
b<--2
e<-50 

set.seed(n)
X<-rnorm(n, -e/b, 2) 
Y<-10000/(1+exp(b*X+e))+rnorm(n, 0, 200) 
plot(X, Y)

dane<-data.frame(Y,X)
```

and wanted to use the getInitial function. I wanted to calculate ANYTHING by the function but it doesn't work. The documentation says

```
Usage
getInitial(object, data, ...)
Arguments
object  
a formula or a selfStart model that defines a nonlinear regression model

data    
a data frame in which the expressions in the formula or arguments to the selfStart model can be evaluated

... 
optional additional arguments
```

so I tried

```
getInitial(Y~X, data=dane)
```

or

```
getInitial(object=Y~X, data=dane)
```

or

```
library("plyr")
getInitial(object=as.formula(Y~X), data=dane)
```

But I always get

```
Error in object[[3L]][[1L]] : object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable
```

Could you explain me how I'm supposed to use this annoying function?

Comment: Why are you trying to use this function? The help page says "this function evaluates initial parameter estimates for a nonlinear regression model" but you don't seem to have a formula for a nonlinear regression. Further more it expects something that looks more like a function call on the right side of the formula. The `?getInitial` help page has a working example at the bottom in the "examples" section. Maybe there is a different function which would better suit your needs.

Comment: I'd like to evaluate initial parameters in nonlinear regression :) Isn't linear regression a particular example of nonlinear regression? I don't fully understand what is allowed in defining formulas in R which is why I tried out something as simple as possible. If you can modify my example to make it working, pelase go ahead. I know there is a working example in the help, but it exploits an example of selfStart functions which I also don't understand -_-